# Move view away from overlapping in ConstraintLayout (minimum constraint)

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

On some screens the text and image overlap. In that case I want to move the text upwards.

[image]

I place a TextView at a percentage position using a guideline. This is the preferred position of the text. Under it is an image with layout_width="match_parent" and ratio preserved. Depending on the screen aspect ratio, the image will become high enough to overlap with the text. In that case, I want the text to move upwards. So I want a "minimum constraint" of like 8dp between the text and image.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guidelineGoldenRatio"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.381966" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Keep me from overlapping"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guidelineGoldenRatio"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guidelineGoldenRatio"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_supercat_popular" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on Cheticamp's answer:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guidelineGoldenRatio"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.381966" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Barrier
        android:id="@+id/barrier"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:barrierDirection="top"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="imageView, guidelineGoldenRatio" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Keep me from overlapping"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/barrier"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/barrier"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:paddingTop="18dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_supercat_popular" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Note: the minimum distance between text and image goes into image padding. This padding should also compensate for half text height (when centering text vertically around guideline).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [Barrier](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/Barrier) widget. Set the barrier's diection to "Top" and set the reference ids to your image and the guideline. (If you can't reference the guideline, constrain a Space widget to the guideline and set the Space widget's id in the referenced ids of the barrier.)

Now constrain the text to the barrier with an `8dp` margin. The text will now float with the barrier which will always be `8dp` above the higher of the guideline and image.

Comment: Thank you! A Barrier is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

How about binding TextView to the Image, and setting padding simply? The image would be always screen-wide, and having a height that depends on the screen type - but the text would be always 8dp over the image.

```
    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Keep me from overlapping"
            android:paddingBottom="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guidelineGoldenRatio"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
    
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_supercat_popular" />
```